# Expected Identifier NSString on application load

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I am trying to define a NSString at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but I am getting a Expected Identifier error. Am I placing the NSString baseURL in the wrong location?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

NSString* baseURL = nil;

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    baseURL = [@"http://mytesturl.com"];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be brackets around your string. Try:

```
baseURL = @"http://mytesturl.com";
```